# Swift 2: Array of keys from dictionary only printing to console, crashes before successful build

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift2

I wanted to fill each Table View cell (each row) in a Table View with the keys of a dictionary, so that, after tapping a row, the associated values for that key are called (the values are an array of Strings) and displayed in a new View.

I created a new array from the keys of the dictionary and called them. Xcode crashed, but the keys printed to the console, but they were in a totally different order than in the original dictionary (it was a set order, NOT alphabetical).

Comment: Crashed with what error ? Can you please also  post relevant code also?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. When you get the array of keys the order of that array is not defined.